# Pandas: from rows to multiple columns, grouped by

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been stuck on something for a good while now. I've looked at existing threads first, but couldn't find anything that mixed `get_dummies()` and aggregation.

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
def getTags(serie):
    tokens = word_tokenize(serie)
    tags = pos_tag(tokens)
    tags = [t[1] for t in tags if t[0] not in punctuation]
    result = " | ".join(tags)
    return result

df = pd.DataFrame({"Text": sentences})
df["Tags"] = df["Text"].apply(lambda x: getTags(x))
df
```

[image]

Where the "Tags" serie can be either an array or a " | " separated string depending on whether the `getTags()` function returns `tags` or `result`.

I'm trying to get each POS tag within the "Tags" serie to have its own dedicated serie. For instance:

```
Col1 | Col2
blue | A B A C
red  | B A C C C C D
```

would become:

```
Col1 | A | B | C | D
blue | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0
red  | 1 | 1 | 4 | 1
```

Back to my dataframe, I've tried:

```
(
df["Tags"]
.str
.get_dummies()
)
```

Which correctly splits the tags, but creates duplicate columns (makes sense, I didn't aggregate anything):

[image]

I then thought of transposing that, doing a `groupby()` and a `sum()` and transposing back again:

```
(
df["Tags"]
.str
.get_dummies()
.T
.reset_index()
.groupby("index", as_index=False)
.sum()
)
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work my tags rows ("index" column) still show duplicate values:

[image]

Questions:

- is this the right approach?
- if yes, what am I doing wrong after transposing the dummies results?
- if no, how would you do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
'col1': ['blue', 'red'],
'col2': ['A|B|A|C', 'B|A|C|C|C|C|D'],
})

df['col2']=df['col2'].str.split('|')

df = ( df.explode(column='col2')
         .reset_index(drop=True)
       )

df['cumcount'] = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).cumcount()+1

df = ( df.drop_duplicates(subset=['col1', 'col2'], keep='last')
         .pivot(index='col1', columns='col2')
         .fillna(0)
         .droplevel(level=0, axis=1)
         .astype(int)
        )

df.columns.name=''

print(df)
```

```
      A  B  C  D
col1            
blue  2  1  1  0
red   1  1  4  1
```

Comment: You're an absolute legend! That worked perfectly :)

Thank you so much!